# How to extract "login" from url

Tags: jquery

```
   var current_url = window.location.pathname;
    //alert(current_url);
    if(current_url == "/login"){
      alert('here');
    }
```

> *Example*: ***hello.com/login*** and **hello.com/login/authenticate**

Only need to extract "login" from the url addresses so that I could remove html bunch if we are on these url address..the code above only works if on /login. But how to extract 'login' itself so that it can do something if it is /login or /login/authenticate?

thanks

**Update**

```
var current_url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    //alert(current_url);

    for(var i=0; i<current_url.length; i++){
      if(current_url[i] == "login"){
        // alert('here');
      }
    }
```

It works but not sure if it is proper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check it would be:

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('/login') === 0){
    alert('Yes it does !!')
}
```

This checks for the path to ***start with*** `/login` which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This code is working.if url have that login variable. that may fetch the value

```
var login = getUrlVars()["login"];

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: thanks but it is a bit longer especially when I only have two logins

Answer (score 1):

```
if(current_url.indexOf("/login") != -1){
      alert('here');
}
```

Comment: if `/login` is present it will return a value > -1. -1 indicates the substring is not present, so != -1 will indicate the substring is present. Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) about indexOf

Comment: @joe The value returned is the position of the searched string; the first position is 0, so -1 is invalid (ie non-existant).  Putting it in an if condition tests for a "truthy" condition.  An alternative could be to use `if(content_url.contains("/login"))` which will return just true/false.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `indexOf`:

```
if (current_url.indexOf('/login') > -1) {
    // Do something
}
```

It [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) the index of the first occurrence of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var input = "login";
if (current_url.indexOf(input)>-1)
   alert(current_url.substr(current_url.indexOf(input),input.length));
```